# Why does the code throw an error 'variable' is not defined

Tags: python

My code:

```
def divide(x,y):

    div = divmod(x,y)
    return div

query = input("Enter numbers separated with a comma to divide: ")
divide(int(query.split(',')[0]),int(query.split(',')[1]))
print(div)
```

Why does it throw the error:

```
NameError: name 'div' is not defined.
```

Comment: Because it doesn't exist in that scope.

Comment: Judging by your question history, you’ve used PHP for a while? It works exactly the same way. https://ideone.com/v8aRCN

Comment: if you want more info: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Comment: @Ryan yes, I used PHP for quite a while but never came across PHP this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `div` is a local variable, and is local to the `divide` function, so it's unknown everywhere else. You can try either:

1. calling the function inside the print function:

   ```
   def divide(x,y):
     div = divmod(x,y)
     return div

   query = input("Enter numbers separated with a comma to divide: ")
   print(divide(int(query.split(',')[0]),int(query.split(',')[1])))
   ```
2. or using a global variable:

   ```
   def divide(x,y):
     div = divmod(x,y)
     return div

   query = input("Enter numbers separated with a comma to divide: ")
   div = divide(int(query.split(',')[0]),int(query.split(',')[1]))
   print(div)
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't that elimnated the purpose of the function divide() when you do the print directly?

I want to use the def

Comment: No it doesn't **if** you **just** want to print it. If you wanna use later then use the second method, which is storing it in a global variable.

Comment: The second method doesn't use a global variable, it's just a normal variable in the outer scope that happens to have the same name as the local variable in the function.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Which means it's a global variable and can be accessed and modified by other functions using the keyword `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `div` is a local variable inside the function `divide`, and you are trying to access it as a global variable.

Should that code be:

```
def divide(x,y):
    div = divmod(x,y)
    return div

query = input("Enter numbers separated with a comma to divide: ")
print(divide(int(query.split(',')[0]),int(query.split(',')[1])))
```